# Make Visible/Unvisible Annotations with Lines (mathplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I have a graph with 2 lines and used the check button to make visible/invisible lines. However, I could not manage to make the same thing to annotations. I wanna when I check label2 make visible/invisible annotations too. I couldn't find any solution from here or web. Any idea?

Here is example of my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons

kansekeri=[333, 111, 111]
inshiz=[3.0, 3.0, 2.5]
zaman=['01-04-2021 04:02', '01-04-2021 04:02', '01-04-2021 04:02']


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
fig.canvas.set_window_title('-')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot()
l0,=ax1.plot(zaman, inshiz, color='tab:blue', marker='.', label='İnsülin Hızı')
ax1.set_xlabel('Tarih - Saat')
ax1.set_ylabel('İnsülin Hızı (u/h)', color='tab:blue')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y',labelcolor='tab:blue')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=7)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
l1,=ax2.plot(zaman, kansekeri, color='tab:red', marker='.', label="Kan Şekeri")
ax2.set_ylabel('Kan Şekeri',color='tab:red')
ax2.tick_params(labelcolor='tab:red')

for x,y in zip(zaman,kansekeri):
    label = "{:.1f}".format(y)
    ann=plt.annotate(label, # this is the text
                 (x,y),
                 textcoords="offset points",
                 xytext=(0,7),
                 ha='center',fontsize=7)

lines = [l0, l1]
rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.7, 0.1, 0.15])
labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in lines]
visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in lines]
check = CheckButtons(rax, labels, visibility)

def func(label):
    index = labels.index(label)
    lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())
    plt.draw()

check.on_clicked(func)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also save the annotations in a list: `annotations = [plt.annotate(f"{y:.1f}", (x, y), ...) for x, y in zip(zaman, kansekeri)]` and then do something similar as with the lines.

Here is some example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons

kansekeri = [333, 111, 111]
inshiz = [3.0, 3.0, 2.5]
zaman = ['01-04-2021 04:02', '01-04-2021 04:02', '01-04-2021 04:02']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
fig.canvas.set_window_title('-')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot()
l0, = ax1.plot(zaman, inshiz, color='tab:blue', marker='.', label='İnsülin Hızı')
ax1.set_xlabel('Tarih - Saat')
ax1.set_ylabel('İnsülin Hızı (u/h)', color='tab:blue')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:blue')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=7)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
l1, = ax2.plot(zaman, kansekeri, color='tab:red', marker='.', label="Kan Şekeri")
ax2.set_ylabel('Kan Şekeri', color='tab:red')
ax2.tick_params(labelcolor='tab:red')

annotations = [plt.annotate(f"{y:.1f}",
                            (x, y),
                            textcoords="offset points",
                            xytext=(0, 7),
                            ha='center', fontsize=7)
               for x, y in zip(zaman, kansekeri)]
lines = [l0, l1]

rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.7, 0.1, 0.15])
labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in lines]
visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in lines]
check = CheckButtons(rax, labels, visibility)

def func(label):
    index = labels.index(label)
    new_line_visibility = not lines[index].get_visible()
    lines[index].set_visible(new_line_visibility)
    if index == 1:
        for ann in annotations:
            ann.set_visible(new_line_visibility)
    plt.draw()

check.on_clicked(func)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you so much. I was found a solution with different variables but this was better.